# how to enable public read access to an S3 bucket in October 2023 with AWS java sdk 1.12.x?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

It seems something changed in April 2023 and now my ACLs do not work anymore. It seems I have to disable public access block from AWS console and then make a policy, that allow public read to my bucket.

I managed to read my index.html from the web, but only by manually disabling the "Block all public access" from AWS console. I am creating buckets dynamically from my code and cannot open the console for every individual bucket.

Changing the public access block from code just gives me Access Denied. The policy installs ok. How to get public read access from java code? My code follows:

```
public S3_UpdaterController()
{
    
    s3client.createBucket("ecotest123456789");
    List buckets = s3client.listBuckets();
    
    for (Object object : buckets) {
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
    
    String bucketname = "ecotest123456789";
    
    String initialString = "<html>test</html>";
    java.io.InputStream targetStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());
    
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("ecotest123456789", "index.html", targetStream,null);
    //s3client.deleteBucketPolicy(bucketname);
   
    
    s3client.setBucketPolicy(bucketname, getPublicReadPolicy(bucketname));
    
    BucketPolicy bucket_policy = s3client.getBucketPolicy(bucketname);
    
    System.out.println(bucket_policy.getPolicyText());
    
    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read); //all users or authenticated
    //putObjectRequest.setAccessControlList(acl);
    
    s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);//.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    s3client.setBucketWebsiteConfiguration(bucketname,new BucketWebsiteConfiguration("index.html"));
    
    //THIS ONE FAILS WITH ACCESS DENIED
    s3client.setPublicAccessBlock(new SetPublicAccessBlockRequest().withBucketName(bucketname));
    
    
}

public static String getPublicReadPolicy(String bucket_name) {
    Policy bucket_policy = new Policy().withStatements(
            new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
                    .withPrincipals(Principal.AllUsers)
                    .withActions(S3Actions.GetObject)
                    .withResources(new Resource(
                            "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket_name + "/*")));
    return bucket_policy.toJson();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Push to S3 now works and the index.html is visible from the browser

```
    public S3_UpdaterController()
{
    
    s3client.createBucket("ecotest123456789");
    List buckets = s3client.listBuckets();
    
    for (Object object : buckets) {
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
    
    String bucketname = "ecotest123456789";
    
    String initialString = "<html>test</html>";
    java.io.InputStream targetStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.getBytes());
    
    ObjectMetadata objm = new ObjectMetadata();// .setContentType("text/html");
    objm.setContentType("text/html");
    
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("ecotest123456789", "index.html", targetStream,objm);
    //s3client.deleteBucketPolicy(bucketname);
   
    
    //s3client.setBucketPolicy(bucketname, getPublicReadPolicy(bucketname));
    
    BucketPolicy bucket_policy = s3client.getBucketPolicy(bucketname);
    
    System.out.println(bucket_policy.getPolicyText());
    
    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read); //all users or authenticated
    //putObjectRequest.setAccessControlList(acl);
    
    s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);//.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    s3client.setBucketWebsiteConfiguration(bucketname,new BucketWebsiteConfiguration("index.html"));
    
    //THIS ONE WAS NEEDED
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration pabc = new PublicAccessBlockConfiguration();
    pabc.setBlockPublicPolicy(false);
    
    //NOW THIS WORKS
    s3client.setPublicAccessBlock(new SetPublicAccessBlockRequest().withBucketName(bucketname).withPublicAccessBlockConfiguration(pabc));
    
    
}

public static String getPublicReadPolicy(String bucket_name) {
    Policy bucket_policy = new Policy().withStatements(
            new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
                    .withPrincipals(Principal.AllUsers)
                    .withActions(S3Actions.GetObject)
                    .withResources(new Resource(
                            "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket_name + "/*")));
    return bucket_policy.toJson();
}
```